# RStudio does not show any pane

Tags: r, qt, rstudio

After last update (I'm using Manjaro GNU/Linux distribution) I am not able to see any pane when opening RStudio. Only the Toolbar and buttons with icons like that to open new or existent files, open folders, and save files are shown.

If I go to View -> Panes, and change options there, nothing seems to happen, or a tiny window is open where only apply and OK buttons are visible. If other options are selected, eg. File -> New File, a bunch of text appears for a short time and then disappears, but nothing is shown after that. Similarly, a message indicating **RStudio window.program_mode = "desktop"** appears momentarily when opening the application.

If RStudio is opened from the command line terminal, the following error messages appear:

> Qt WebEngine resources not found at /share/qt/resources. Trying parent directory...
>
> Qt WebEngine resources not found at /share/qt. Trying application directory...
>
> Qt WebEngine resources not found at /usr/lib/qt/libexec. Trying fallback directory... The application MAY NOT work.
>
> Path override failed for key base::DIR_QT_LIBRARY_DATA and path '/home/user/.QtWebEngineProcess'
>
> Installed Qt WebEngine locales directory not found at location /share/qt/translations/qtwebengine_locales. Trying application directory...
>
> Qt WebEngine locales directory not found at location /usr/lib/qt/libexec/qtwebengine_locales. Trying fallback directory... Translations MAY NOT not be correct.
>
> Path override failed for key ui::DIR_LOCALES and path '/home/user/.QtWebEngineProcess'
>   [0101/102738.515189:ERROR:resource_bundle.cc(887)] Failed to load /home/user/.QtWebEngineProcess/qtwebengine_resources.pak
>
> Some features may not be available.
>   [0101/102738.515234:ERROR:resource_bundle.cc(887)] Failed to load /home/user/.QtWebEngineProcess/qtwebengine_resources_100p.pak
>
> Some features may not be available.
>   [0101/102738.515240:ERROR:resource_bundle.cc(887)] Failed to load /home/user/.QtWebEngineProcess/qtwebengine_resources_200p.pak
>
> Some features may not be available.
>   [0101/102738.515965:WARNING:resource_bundle_qt.cpp(117)] locale_file_path.empty() for locale
>
> Use of deprecated not thread-safe setter, use setUrlRequestInterceptor instead.
>
> Use of deprecated not thread-safe setter, use setUrlRequestInterceptor instead.
>
> "Invalid splitter position detected: 304/0"

So far, I've tried to reinstalling RStudio and qt, and deleting `.rstudio-desktop/`, but no luck, and I am not able to figure out what is going on. Any ideas?

Comment: Is `R` working on it's own in the terminal?

Comment: Yes, it is working. I only had to reinstall the `tk` package for being able to install R packages again. Other than that it works as expected.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had the same issue on Arch and found this solution on the bug reports: https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/64973

It was solved by adding this /usr/lib/qt/libexec/qt.conf

```
[Paths]
Prefix = /usr/lib/qt
Data = /usr/share/qt
Translations = /usr/share/qt/translations
```

Hope it helps someone else.

Comment: This worked well on Manjaro now. I installed rstudio desktop from this AUR: https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/rstudio-desktop/